# ImageField reads image info from disk, even if width_field and height_field are populated

Tags: django, image, disk, django-models

Django's `ImageField` reads image headers from disk to determine an image's width and height, even though my model has dedicated fields to hold both of them, specified by `width_field` and `height_field`. I have about 20,000,000 images, so this isn't helping my response times.

Looking through the source code, it seems like Django reads the image once (regardless of the values of `width_field` and `height_field`) and stores the computed size as an attribute on `ImageFile`, which will get deleted after every request. In effect, every time I grab the size of the image in a template, I read the image header.

The disk is touched only if I access the image's width and height using the properties of `ImageField` (from `ImageFieldFile`), so if I just access the width and height fields directly from my model, the image is not read from disk.

What is the reasoning behind this behavior? Is there any way to prevent `ImageField` from reading the image info from disk whenever I access the width and height of an image using the properties exposed by `ImageField`?